# In Rails 6, a link for delete without resource route is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud

For a CRUD operation in Rails 6, I am not using the resource route. I write an html link to delete a post with `<a></a>` tag. Instead of delete, this link redirects to the show page with a get request.

Here is the link

```
<a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>" data-method="delete" >Delete</a>
```

Here is the routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/posts', to: 'posts#index'
  get '/posts/new', to: 'posts#new'
  post '/posts', to: 'posts#create'
  get '/posts/:id', to: 'posts#show'
  get '/posts/:id/edit', to: 'posts#edit'
  patch '/posts/:id', to: 'posts#update'
  delete '/posts/:id', to: 'posts#destroy'

end
```

Here is the posts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
   @post.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Post was successfully destroyed." }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
 end
```

Here is the application.js file

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

Comment: see if you have <script src="/packs/js/application-......js"></script> in page source

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rails way to create an a link to a delete method:

<%= link_to "delete", *your_posts_path(id)*, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>

Comment: open your web page in a browser, then view source.  what does the HTML <a> link look like in the browser code when the page is rendered in a browser?